# how to faint my image color when i shake my iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am creating a shake application in iphone such that when i shake my iphone their is an image on my iphone .when i shake my iphone the color of the image should get faint .How is it possible.Please anybody help me in solving this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not it is possible use UIAccelerometer Class. you will get update intervals of shaking device. Using this intervals you have reducing the alpha value of your image.

Comment: which function of accelerometer class should be called

Comment: i have defined kupdateinterval (1.0f/10.0f) so how to use this so that my image color will get faint

Comment: @Abhishek, use UIAccelerometerDelegate Protocol methods for it.

Comment: if you have change your color of image then you must have to change in its RGB values.

Answer (score 2):

UIResponder has a methods motionEnded:withEvent:, motionStarted:withEvent: and motionCanceled:withEvent:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Use these to detect the phone shaking, then set the alpha on your UIImage acordingly:

```
UIImage *yourImage;
yourImage.alpha = 0.5;
```

Note, that to use those motion methods, your object must be firstResponder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the UIAccelerometer for this purpose.You can explore in detail from the below mentioned link.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html

Cheers